# EF Core and ASP.NET not inserting child object to array

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I come from EF 6 where inserting a child object into a parent entity's list would look something like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(int id, MenuViewModel menu){
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest("Something is wrong with the model");

    var restaurant = await db.Restaurants.Where(r => r.Id == id).Include(r=> r.Menus).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (restaurant == null)
        return BadRequest("That restaurant does not exist");

    var menuModel = Mapper.Map<Menu>(menu);
    restaurant.Menus.Add(menuModel);
    db.Restaurants.Update(restaurant);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(Mapper.Map<MenuViewModel>(menuModel));
}
```

Comment: There are several things missing for people to be able to analyze this and help you : The definition of your various relevant classes (MenuViewModel, Menu in particular) and the actual content of menu parameter when you executed the action.

Comment: I think you should add your new menu to context manualy

Answer (score 0):

Try add your child to db then save its should be work

```
[HttpPost, Route("{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(int id, MenuViewModel menu){
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest("Something is wrong with the model");

var restaurant = await db.Restaurants.Where(r => r.Id == id).Include(r=> r.Menus).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (restaurant == null)
    return BadRequest("That restaurant does not exist");

var menuModel = Mapper.Map<Menu>(menu);
restaurant.Menus.Add(menuModel);
db.Menus.Add(menuModel); //Add to DBContext
db.Restaurants.Update(restaurant);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();

return Ok(Mapper.Map<MenuViewModel>(menuModel));
```

}